# Why does my code print [I@87816d when i run this code?

Tags: java, arrays

```
/*
 * Given an array of positive ints, return a new array of length "count" containing the
 * first even numbers 
 * from the original array. The original array will contain at least "count" even numbers.
 */

public class StringEx 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] nums = {2,3,5,6,8};
        int count = 2;
        StringEx s1 = new StringEx();
        System.out.println(s1.copyEvens(nums, count));

    }
    public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) 
    {
       int[] n=new int[count];
       int c=0;

        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]%2==0&&c!=count)
            {
                n[c]=nums[i];
                c++;

            }
        }

        return n;
    }
}

// Output:[I@87816d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays don't have a nice `toString` method. They use [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which gives

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

which is usually unhelpful. Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) if you want a readable representation.

Comment: How do i get to know the result? This System.out.println(s1.copyEvens(Arrays.toString(nums), count)); is not acceptable for sure!

Comment: @Nandan: You're `toString`ing the wrong thing. Convert the `copyEvens` return value, not the input.